# no wireless after fresh install using wireless

Tags: wireless

I have just installed 14.04 from dvd.  The iso ubuntu recognized my wifi, and connected to it.  After the install completed and reboot, the new system doesn't have wireless connections.   Suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) contains a nice link to a small program which collects the information needed to help you

Comment: I'm very glad to see that someone has reported that unlikely set of circumstances.  In other words, you've proven that the installation DVD is essentially "smarter" than the finished product.

Comment: Can the question be edited to include at least the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `dmesg | grep firmware`

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion.  Please do try to fix it with the help you get here, and make clear what worked (if anything) so that others can benefit from your solution.

If things turn out such that you cannot fix your installation, please rest assured that the previous LTS release, 12.04LTS, still works well and is apparently supported for 2.5 more years (five years in total).  I'm not resisting progress, but as your complaint is not remotely rare, and as I have yet to learn of a solution to your problem, I feel I should at least share what I know that could benefit you.